# Searching Sqlite Database using Exact Keyword

Tags: android, sqlite

i`m trying to search a Sqlite Database , with this condition : i want to find a string using an Exact Keyword. let me explain this to you .
i have 3 rows as follow :

- catching cold
- i have a cat
- two cats was seen in your house yesterday

---

i want to search these rows with keyword "cat" and i expect this result :

- i have a cat

---

i am using this SQL code so far :

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE Mycolumn Like '%cat%'
```

But Returning Result is All these 3 Rows:

- catching cold
- i have a cat
- two cats was seen in your house yesterday

What can i do to get my expected result?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` character in the argument of a LIKE clause matches any string, including the empty string. Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't have the REGEXP function built in (and Android's SQLite doesn't have it).

What you can do instead is use FTS (full text search). How to do so is described here: https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2

Using your example, you would set it up like so:

```
create virtual table textsearch using fts4(content);
insert into textsearch (content) values ('catching cold'), ('i have a cat'), ('two cats was seen in your house yesterday')
```

Then you can do a simple text query with the `MATCH` operator:

```
select * from textsearch where content match 'cat';
```

If you try the above in a sqlite3 shell, you'll see it returns only 'i have a cat'. There's a lot more you can do with the match operator, explained on the page I linked above.

Comment: How do I match for an half word.Suppose my virtual table column have "Dogs are good" and I query for "are" How would I do the match?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with a special pattern for word boundaries.

```
Select * FROM MyTable WHERE Mycolumn = 'cat'
```

Corrected my answer i think that should work.

Comment: SQLite docs: No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message.